# Connection refused: when connecting a java client to an Android server(Emulator)

Tags: java, android, sockets

I've tried out almost everything.

1. Forwarding from ADB Shell using adb forward TCP:12345 TCP:12345
2. Using 10.0.2.2 (without forwarding) to listen to my host machine
3. Setting the INTERNET permission in the manifest
4. Setting the thread policy to permit all functions

I'm running my client java program in 12345 port and I have a ServerSocket in the Android program that listens over the same port. But when I run my client (*after running the server program on the emulator*) and enter the String that I want to transfer, I get the exception saying 'Connection Refused'.

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Here's my server program:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    String mClientMsg = "";
    Thread myCommsThread = null;

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 12345;
    protected static final int MSG_ID = 0x1337;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Nothing from client yet");
        setContentView(tv);
        this.myCommsThread = new Thread(new CommsThread());
        this.myCommsThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
            ss.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_ID:
                // TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                tv.setText(mClientMsg);
                setContentView(tv);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    class CommsThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            Socket s = null;
            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Message m = new Message();
                m.what = MSG_ID;
                try {
                    if (s == null)
                        s = ss.accept();
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    String st = null;
                    st = input.readLine();
                    mClientMsg = st;
                    myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
               }
```

My Java client program is as follows:

```
public class TCPSender {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the file name:");
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            String f = dis.readLine();
            File f1 = new File(f);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);

            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            pw.println(f);
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = fr.read()) != -1)
                pw.println(c);
            System.out.println("File content are sent....");
            fr.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance Windows firewall (or equivalent) might be blocking the connection?

Comment: Nope, i've turned down the firewall and besides it works between two java programs...